# (Quantile regression) AR(1) variable in the design matrix

Tags: r, autocorrelation, autoregressive, quantile-regression

I'm not doing a pure QAR (quantile auto regression) but I do have a lagged dependent variable (AR(1)) as a predictor. I'm using the `quantreg` package in `R` to do it. I have two very closely related questions:

(1) I use `quantreg` in `R` to do my QRs. Do I need to do anything fancy to be fine by putting an AR(1) term on the RHS?

(2) Is it fine to use AR(1) term as a regressor to deal with autocorrelation in quantile regression as you can with OLS? Or is QR different in this regards?